# docsplit gem pdf to text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, docsplit

Well basically I have the same problems as discussed here: http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2014/08/13/pdf-to-plain-text-processing-using-docsplit/ 
But the solution that they propose in docsplit doesn't work.

```
 Docsplit.extract_text(filepath, {:pdf_opts => ‘-layout’, output: ‘tmp_text_file’})
```

the **:pdf_opts => ‘-layout’** option doesn't do anything and I can't find any documentation about options like that, thus I get a single word per line in the output text file.

Does anyone know how to get an accurate text file ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a sample pdf and output so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read blog post carefully internally processing

```
 :pdf_opts => ‘-layout’
```

is not supported yet by master branch of docsplit gem. For this you need to use https://github.com/documentcloud/docsplit/pull/114. So use

```
gem 'docsplit', git: 'git://github.com/narutosanjiv/docsplit.git'
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: It worked, looking good so far, still have to do a little bit more testing.